# Swagger 2 + spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, swagger

I'm trying to expose rest API with Spring Integration and document it with swagger. Is it even possible ? I cannot find any docs or example to make it work.

My swagger docket bean:

```
Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
   .select()
   .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
   .paths(PathSelectors.any())
   .build();
```

And simple flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
            .requestPayloadType(String.class))
            .channel("httpRequest")
            .get();
}
```

I use spring boot:2.0.1 and springfox-swagger2 : 2.8.0

Thank in advance,
Mateusz

Comment: What does this Swagger do? Maybe there is just no such a metadata exposed from the Spring Integration perspective to it work properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration is currently not supported by springfox, although they have provided a generalization which seems to make it possible, based upon  IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/550

They are asking for a PR which would implement this:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/797

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/open/api/**")).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see the difference, expect paths and swagger version. Should it work with spring-integration ?